# Проблема в указывании пути к файлу в bash

Tags: bash

Каждый раз когда мне нужно указать путь к какому-либо файлу или папке bash принимает пробел в "Рабочий стол" за пробел в адресе, тем самым принимая два аргумента вместо одного, что приводит к ошибке. Изменить название рабочего стола нельзя.

Comment: Кавычки придумали не для вашей проблемы?

Comment: + либо экранируйте пробел `Рабочий\ стол`, + либо сделайте симлинк `ln -s Рабочий\ стол Desktop; cd Desktop`